# Convert SpatialCollections to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, intersection, shapefile

I am struggling to convert an object of class `SpatialCollections` to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. 
My input files are both shapefiles and `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` objects. They can be accessed [here](https://ufile.io/v6uct).

I do an intersection of both objects:

```
SPDF_A <- shapefile("SPDF_A")
SPDF_B <- shapefile("SPDF_B")
intersection <- gIntersection(gBuffer(SPDF_A, width=0), gBuffer(SPDF_B, width=0))
```

The result is:

```
> intersection
class       : SpatialCollections
```

Setting `gBuffer(... , byid=T)` or `gBuffer(... , byid=F)` seems to make no difference.

I use `gIntersection` and `gBuffer(... , width=0)` insetead of `intersect` in order to avoid geometrical problems (`Self-intersection`). 
This is part of a larger loop. I need to get the intersection as `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` because it will be saved as shp file in a following step.

```
writeOGR(intersection, ".", layer=paste0("Int_SPDF_A-SPDF_B"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

This is not possible from a `SpatialCollections` object. In order to convert this to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` I tried:

```
intersection <- as(intersection ,"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
intersection <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(intersection)
intersection <- readOGR(intersection, layer = "intersection")
```

Nothing works. Does anybody have a solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, according to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.4-2/topics/SpatialCollections-class) SpatialCollections is kind of a container format that can "hold SpatialPoints, SpatialLines, SpatialRings, and SpatialPolygons  (**without attributes**)". If you need the data frame part of your SpatialPolygonsDataFrame ("attribute table" in GIS language), you'll have to work around that somehow. If, on the other hand, you're only interested in the spatial information (the polygons without the data attached to them) try the following:

```
str(intersection, max.level = 3)
```

suggests that the @polyobj is nothing but a SpatialPolygons object. Hence

```
mySpoly <- intersection@polyobj
```

should do the trick and

```
class(mySpoly)
```

suggests that we indeed now have a SpatialPolygons.

You need to convert that to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame before exporting:

```
mySpolyData <- as(mySpoly, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
writeOGR(mySpolyData, ".", layer=paste0("Int_SPDF_A-SPDF_B"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```